# How to monitor ios's process, memory, GPU without inspect in app code？

Tags: python, ios

Is there any tools help me communicate with ios to know it's Memory, cpu, process, just like xcode's Instruments？

While I know  `xcrun xctrace` can get the data I want, but I cannt use python decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "`xcrun xctrace export`" to decode trace file.

description:
Export given .trace using supplied query to the XML file format that can be later read and post-processed

For example:

```
xcrun xctrace export --input recording.trace --output recording.xml --xpath '/trace-toc/run[@number="1"]/data/table[@schema="activity-monitor-process-ledger"]'
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the xml to csv?

Comment: Yes, I've tried like [this](https://github.com/Vancheung/TestEngineering/blob/master/_1_Programming/Python/LittleTools/TraceDecoder.py)